# Close Soft Keyboard on start App

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a simple app with 2 edits and a button, the problem is that when I start running my app, the soft keyboard automatically appears while I have not do anything. I want to when I click on Edittext, soft keyboard will appears? Thank you all

MainActivity.xml

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:hint="Email/Phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I have read some post and do these things, but they only work when I click the button:

```
InputMethodManager imm;
imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(username.getWindowToken(),0);
```

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"  in parent layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this use **`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`** in Your Manifest where your are decraing YOur Activity like below code

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="XXX.XXX.XXXX"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: thanks u very much. i will accept. good day man :)

Comment: @tuấnvũhữu happy to help you enjoy codding